# How do I fix a "Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream" with the Maven shade plugin?

Tags: maven

When running the Maven Shade plugin, I get the following error. How can I debug this?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.0:shade (make-shade) on project csprocessor-client: Error creating shaded jar: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.0:shade (make-shade) on project csprocessor-client: Error creating shaded jar: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error creating shaded jar: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:551)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:411)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.addRemappedClass(DefaultShader.java:259)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.shade(DefaultShader.java:151)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:484)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that with the m2eclipse plugin, you can actually debug a maven plugin as it is executing. To do this you need to what code you want to step into, which you can do by setting the **Debug Output** option in the Maven Run Configuration. You'll also need to set the **Resolve Workspace artifacts** option.

[image]

With these two options I could click the file location listed in the error (ZipFile.java:411 in this case), set a break point, and use **Debug As > Maven Build** to run the Maven build in debug mode. Once the breakpoint was hit I could tell which file was causing the error, and repackage it using the [JAR command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html). Even though the JAR file in question could be opened with a GUI archive tool, once repackaged with the JAR command I could successfully run the Maven Shade plgin.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if this was caused by a JAR that was corrupted during download, a quick way of forcing a re-download is to run [`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) in the *shading* project. This [removes all dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html) (direct and transitive) of the project from the local Maven repository and downloads them anew.